# My 1997 lancer jerks when accelerates and shakes when idling

Tags: engine, electrical, ignition, misfire, shaking

i got a big problem, I have a 1997 Mitsubishi lancer, with a 1.6 liters engine, a 4g92 to be exact, and when Its idling it keeps shaking, the exhaust sound like there are little misfires, but no check engine light, and I heve change the ignition coils, when accelerates it jerks, I have already clean all sensor, maf, Iac valve, throttle body, o2 sensor, also check the knock sensor when I turn on the A/C it comes worse, sometime ago, it lose its ignition timing and got knocking, the mechanic fix it, not sure what has he do, but he change the tps sensor, and now when I load the engine at low rpm, it pops in the exhaust, like sending to much fuel, the car has electrical problems to, like if I put to much load on it, all light come dimmer, and the car shakes even more, really i need help, I know moreless about cars, but even me and other 4 mechanics has no idea what is the problem or the combination of problems, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this points I think I have found the problem, the tps that the mechanic change, was out of adjustment, the shake of the car has almost stop when change the engine mounts, the mini misfires I think thats something internal of the engine but I think I will live with that, also take out the whole throttle body and cleans it and all its passages, I will be updating what things have worked or not, thanks